# How to insert photo in cv without pushing text down?

Tags: graphics, moderncv

I'm creating a cv with moderncv at the moment. I want to insert a photo next to my personal data, but it keeps pushing the text down.(The text is inserted with `\cvline` and `\section` if that helps)

How can I achieve this?

The photo is supposed to go into the empty box in this pic:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235425/moderncv-picture-below-name-and-line-in-casual-style

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it helped you. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer/1854

Answer (score 1):

Please post a [MWE](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-minxampl.html) nexttime.

---

I have a workaround for you.

```
\documentclass[]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\name{}{Lebenslauf}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.7\textwidth}
  \section{Person}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Name}{John Doe}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
  \cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{}
\end{minipage}  \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][][b]{3cm}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{minipage} \\
\section{Work}
\cvitemwithcomment{Adress}{Street Number}{Information}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lebenslauf]

---

You could also take a look at:

1. [ModernCV Banking photo title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201144/moderncv-banking-photo-title)
2. [CV title with an image - modernCV style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326053/cv-title-with-an-image-moderncv-style)
3. [Moderncv casual header - photo right, name and title on the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/moderncv-casual-header-photo-right-name-and-title-on-the-left)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!